# What were the instances, when the devatas had bestowed daughter instead of a son, even though the tapasya was done for getting son only?

Tags: gods, women, children, boon, tapasya

I know two to three instances where a sadhaka asks for a male child and the devatas offered a female child as a result of tapas.

#1: **Manifestation of Draupadi**

Although Drupada asked for only a son

> O Yaja, perform that sacrifice by means of which **I may obtain a son**
> invincible in battle and capable of slaying Drona. Ready am I to give
> thee ten thousand kine

Draupadi also originated from fire. You can read it on the same page provided.

> And there arose, after this from the centre of the sacrificial
> platform, **a daughter also, called Panchali**, who, blest with great good
> fortune, was exceedingly handsome.
>
> [[169, Chaitraratha Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01170.htm)

#2: **Manifestation of Savitri**

Aswathi asked ma Savitri for a son, but ma Savitri bestowed a daughter of the same name (and then a hundred sons later)

> Thereat Aswapati said, 'It is with the desire
> of attaining virtue that I have been engaged in this task. **O goddess,
> may many sons be born unto me worthy of my race!** If thou art pleased
> with me, O goddess, I ask for this boon. The twice-born ones have
> assured me that great merit lieth in having offspring!' Savitri
> replied, 'O king, having already learnt this thy intention, I had
> spoken unto that lord, the Grandsire, about thy sons. Through the
> favour granted by the Self-create, **there shall speedily be born unto
> thee on earth a daughter of great energy. It behoveth thee not to make
> any reply.** Well-pleased, I tell thee this at the command of the
> Grandsire.'
>
> [[291, Pativrata mahatmya Parva,  Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03291.htm)

#3: **[Manifestation of Meenakshi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/when-did-meenakshi-avatarana-and-the-subsequent-rule-of-meenakshi-and-sundareshv)**

Are there any other instances in which devatas bestowed a daughter even though the tapas is performed for a son only?

Answer (score 1):

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam 6.21.:**

> ***With a desire to get a son, he made many presents in profuse quantities.** When copious quantities of ghee were offered as oblations, **there arose, from the fire, a girl beautiful in all respects and endowed with all auspicious signs**.........When the girl arose from the fire, the priest (Hotā) took that lean and thin lady of a nice waist by her arms and presented her to the King and said :-- O King! Accept this daughter, endowed with all auspicious signs. **When Homa was being performed, the daughter came up like the garland Ekāvalī;** therefore this girl became famous in this world by the name Ekāvalī. O Ruler of the earth! **Take this girl, resembling a son and be happy. O King! Viṣṇu, the Deva of the Devas, has given you this Jewel, this daughter; so be contented.***

**Mahabharata Udyoga parva chapter 188.:**

> *"Duryodhana said, 'Tell me, O grandsire, how Sikhandin, O Ganga's son, having before been born a daughter, afterwards became a man, O foremost of warriors.' "Bhishma said, 'O great king, the eldest and beloved queen of king Drupada was, O monarch, childless (at first). During those years, king Drupada, O monarch, paid his adoration to the god Sankara for the sake of offspring, resolving in his mind to compass my destruction and practising the austerest of penances. And he begged Mahadeva, saying, **'Let a son, and not a daughter, be born unto me. I desire, O god, a son for revenging myself upon Bhishma.'** Thereupon, that god of gods said unto him, 'Thou shalt have a child who will be a female and male. Desist, O king, it will not be otherwise.' Returning then to his capital, he addressed his wife, saying, 'O great goddess, great hath been the exertion made by me. Undergoing ascetic austerities, I paid my adorations to Siva, and **I was told by Sambhu that my child becoming a daughter (first) would subsequently become a male person.** And though I solicited him repeatedly, yet Siva said,--This is Destiny's decree. It will not be otherwise. That which is destined must take place!'*

I hope this clarifies your queries.